# Fill empty datas in JS/PHP Chart

Tags: javascript, php, charts, chart.js

I have issue with chart made in JS/PHP.

My point is: Fill all empty values in chart. For example is 18 April, so chart must show all values from last 14 days - 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12 April... (even if are empty) without adding datas in MySQL.

I took style and js of charts from https://github.com/ankane/chartkick.js

Output: https://ibb.co/mZ06cS

How it looks in MySQL: https://ibb.co/jwqpxS

```
<?php
function convert_json ($array_data) {
  $str  =   '';
  foreach($array_data as $key=>$value) {
   if($str<>'')
   $str.=",";
   $str.=   '"'.$value['date_added'].'":'.$value['coins'];
  }
  return $str;
}

$earnings_14days    =   $db->QueryFetchArrayAll('SELECT site_id, SUM(coins) 
as coins, DATE_FORMAT(`date_added`, "%Y-%m-%d") as date_added  FROM 
m_z_analytics WHERE user_id="'.$data['id'].'" AND date_added >= 
(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 14 DAY) GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`date_added`, "%Y-%m- 
%d") ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(`date_added`, "%Y-%m-%d") ASC');
$earnings_14days_data   =   convert_json($earnings_14days);
?>

<div id="library" class="a-chart-1"></div>
<script>
new Chartkick.LineChart("library", {
  <?=$earnings_14days_data?>},
{});
</script>
```

Comment: Chartkickjs doc says: *"Supports Chart.js, Google Charts, and Highcharts"*. Which one do you use?

Comment: Above chart is using _Chart.js_.